# Regarding surah 24 verse 31

Tags: slavery, awrah, verses

In this verse, women are forbidden to show their adornments (or where its worn) EXCEPT to close relatives, the husband and some additional people. The word used "bal" to refer to the husband can also translate to master of a slave as well so does that not mean that a slave woman cannot reveal her adornments just as a free woman shouldn't thus making veiling and awra equal of free and slave women to men outside of the mahrams in the mentioned verse?

Comment: The awrah of slaves is disagreed upon and is discussed [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/79371/). There are other specific texts which give details about the what a slave must cover and what she can reveal. Verse 24:31 is general and rather applies to free women, as evidence it says أو ما ملكت أيمانهن (that which their right hands possess) while a slave woman does not own property.

Comment: @UmH so the word "bal" only refers to husband not master?